# Difference between '-' and '/' in date strings for Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand Dates in javascript and I was essentially experimenting with date values.
I have noticed a weird behavior. My local time is IST.

```
Date.parse("1970/01/01");//-19800000 => this is 330 mins, time difference between IST and UTC
Date.parse("1970-01-01");//0
```

I have read a few resources but couldn't find any which would describe the behavior above.
So the first line of code interprets the date as IST(local time) and the second line of code interprets the date as UTC!!!

Is it the case that dates using '/' are interpreted as local time while dates containing '-' are interpreted as UTC time?

Comment: There is **one** standard date format, that being the ISO standard. Other formats are accepted by some browsers and not by others. [Read the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Your first format is unspecified, and so may or may not be parsed, and if parsed may be parsed in local time or UTC. Your second format is [specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) and will (on compliant JavaScript engines) be parsed as UTC (because it's a date-only string w/o timezone; if it were a date/time string w/o timezone, it would be parsed as local). But beware that that part of the spec (how date-only strings without a timezone specifier should be parsed, UTC or local) moved around a bit. For consistent results (UTC), add a `Z` to the string before parsing it.